# About cardinalities of almost disjoint systems of functions

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

Let us call a system $\{f_i; i\in I\}$ of functions $f_i\colon\omega\to\omega$ *almost disjoint* if the set $\{n\in\omega; f_i(n)=f_j(n)\}$ is finite whenever $i\ne j$. (I am not entirely sure whether this is a standard terminology for such system of functions, but the same name was used in a different question on this site.)

Let $\mathfrak m$ denotes the least cardinality of a maximal almost disjoint system of functions in $\omega^\omega$. One part of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/352330/) in fact shows $\aleph_1 \le \mathfrak m$. A more general version of this lower bound was shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126055/almost-disjoint-functions).

<s>My guess is that</s> we also have $\mathfrak m\le \mathfrak c$, <s>although I don't have a proof for this</s>, since the cardinality of $\omega^\omega$ is $\mathfrak c$. (This was pointed out in a [comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355675/about-cardinalities-of-almost-disjoint-systems-of-functions#comment764534_355675); I have somehow missed this easy estimate. I'll try to get away with the excuse that I was posting this relatively early in the morning. :-)

> - Was such cardinal studied? And if yes, what is it called?
> - <s>Is it true that $\mathfrak m\le \mathfrak c$?</s>
> - Is it perhaps equal to some of other [small uncountable cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum)?

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the wrong button: If $\{f_i : i \in I\}$ is almost disjoint then $f_i \neq  f_j$ for $i \neq j$, so $|I| \leq |\omega^\omega| =\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I've edited my question accordingly. (And I am really ashamed that I have missed this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost disjoint families of functions $\omega \to \omega$ are sometimes called *(pairwise) eventually different* families.  I have seen the notation $\mathfrak{a}_{\mathfrak{e}}$ used for the corresponding cardinal invariant, for example in

> - Yi Zhang, *On a class of m.a.d. families*, J. Symbolic Logic 64 (1999), no.2, pp.737–746, [MR1777782](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1777782).
> - Dilip Raghavan, *Maximal almost disjoint families of functions*, Fund. Math. 204 (2009), no.3, pp.241–282, [MR2520154](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2520154).

Comment: But MAD families sounds so much cooler. One may even prove a theorem on the behavior of MAD families under certain changes (e.g. passing to elementary submodel) and name it after mad families from TV (e.g. Simpsons, Griffins, Addams)...

Comment: @Asaf: But are _MAD_ families as cool as [_very MAD_ families](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2322366), or perhaps [mob families](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1619601)?  Ahhh... set theorists have become quite cynical since Mathias!

Comment: We should talk about NUTBAG "Nowhere Ultra-Tame Borel Almost Generic" sets, which are sets which are really crazy.